# Find a value in a range based on the first two words and return the found value in Excel

Tags: excel, search, range

This does a good job of finding a specific value:

```
=VLOOKUP("Bob Hoskins (ICT)", 'Sheet1 '!C12:G12, TRUE, FALSE)
```

However I only want to search for "Bob Hoskins" in the range and return the full value, which could be "Bob Hoskins (ICT)" of whatever as long as "Bob Hoskins" are the first two words. Heres what I have so far and it works fine if Bob Hoskins is in C12 but wont work if its in D12, E12, F12, G12. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
=IF(LEFT('Sheet1 '!C12:G12,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE('Sheet1 '!C12:G12," ","|",2))-1)="Bob Hoskins",'Sheet1 '!C12:G12,"No")
```

Also if other values are present in the range the formula returns VALUE! I want it to return nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Answer to described question (using VLOOKUP to find any value that starts with a defined value):

`=VLOOKUP("Bob Hoskins*",'Sheet1 '!C12:G12, TRUE, FALSE)`

Answer to actual problem (finding any instance of a value in a row):

`=INDEX(12:12,MATCH("Bob Hoskins*",12:12,FALSE))`

Comment: It doesnt seem to work? Does =VLOOKUP("Bob Hoskins*",'Sheet1 '!C12:G12, TRUE, FALSE) search for only "Bob Hoskins" and then bring back a value such as "Bob Hoskins (science)"? And can "Bob Hoskins" be anywhere in the range?

Comment: It does work if "Bob Hoskins" is in C12 but not if he is in E12?

Comment: **First**, VLOOKUP only works when the first column of your defined range is the column you're looking through.  VLOOKUPS in the range C12:G12 will always look at C12 for Bob Hoskins, then return a corresponding value in a specified cell from this range.  I'm honestly not familiar with your use of TRUE.  What cell in C12:G12 are you trying to capture data from? **Second**, the formula above will look for ANY value (in cell C12) that starts with Bob Hoskins, and return that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm still learning here, I wanted to search the range C12:G12 for "Bob Hoskins" not just C12, there is no guarantee Bob will be in C12, he might be in D12. Maybe VLOOKUP is the wrong funtion as its searching a range across a row

Comment: VLOOKUP finds a value in one column (looks within column C for any value that starts with Bob Hoskins), then looks horizontally (within the same row) to find whatever value you want from a different column. So you want a formula that will search the range C12:G12 and return values with Bob Hoskins?  Can Bob Hoskins appear more than once?  Do you want to know the actual Bob Hoskins value, or do you just want to know if it is there/how many times it is there?

Comment: Bob Hoskins will only appear once within the range but I want the formula to return the cell value with bob hoskins in and that could be "bob hoskins (whatever)". If thats possible, thank you so very much

Comment: Sorry yes, search for Bob Hoskins across the range

Comment: `=INDEX(12:12,MATCH("bob hoskins*",12:12,FALSE))` will return whatever Bob Hoskins value may be in the range.  If you want to know the actual cell reference (as in D12 or E12, etc.) I'll have to figure that out.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir and sorry I was being a bit of a newb.

Comment: For a horizontal range you could also use HLOOKUP, i.e. `=HLOOKUP("bob hoskins*",12:12,1,0)`